# Java IDE *on* iPhone?

Tags: java, iphone, ide

Is there any Eclipse-like (or just any) for developing Java programs from my iPhone? Note that this does not refer to developing java apps for the iPhone. I just want to sometimes develop on my cellphone, even if it is a pain in the ass.

Comment: You mean, do the dev on the iPhone itself?  If so, for the love of pete...why?

Comment: There's editors, including a few with syntax highlighting, but nothing approaching IDE functionality.

Comment: @Aaron  Sometimes I think of stuff out of reach of a computer.

Comment: Then what @DaveNewton mentions is entirely sufficent.

Comment: Considering that full IDEs consume more memory than the iPhone has available in total just to show an empty window, I wouldn't hold my breath. What you could do is VNC into your computer from the iPhone, although the latency would probably kill the usefulness of autocompletion and other muscle-memory-level features.

Comment: [iEditor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ieditor-all-in-one/id434810905?mt=8) and [CodeToGo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8) work by sending your code to a server to be compiled. There are also additional applications for iPad such as `for i` and `Koder`.

Comment: Another option is getting a computer that's easy to keep "in reach" – netbooks are cheaper than iPhones.

Comment: Use VNC or some other remote desktop software :-)

Comment: "Sometimes I think of stuff out of reach of a computer." You can always write your thoughts down. No need to actually implement it immediately.

Comment: Do I really need to justify why I want to program on my iPhone?! Some of you guys are hilarious. Thanks Joe and Inerdia

Comment: @dylandrop: No you do not have to justify, ignore those comments. That is why there are several solutions in the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... type in sourceLair on the market. I think it's free. It's an IDE that works for several languages, including objective c,c,c++,fortran and pascal. Unfortunately it does not have java, but since it's on the phone and you're not doing any SERIOUS coding, then you should stick with c++ because they are essentially the same thing if you're doing simple stuff.

Comment: sourceLair is not in the market, cant find it.

Comment: sorry about that... I don't have an iphone near me atm so I would look on the market for you, but alas... just type in "java" or "c++" on the market, or any other programming language you may be familiar with, and scout for ide's

Comment: He asked for a Java IDE...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a java cloud based IDE (like Exo's http://cloud-ide.com/) and just use your iPhone's browser. I think sourceLair only has an Android based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out CodeToGo by nathaniel Herman in the app store. Never used it yet because it doesn't support .net 4 yet, but seems to have raving reviews.

Answer (score 0):

There is **C/C++** IDE - [CppCode](http://www.cppcode.info).